# Problems passing js data to php page using ajax jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajax

**Hi everyone**

After one week searching what could be the problem I have not discovered what could fix it.

 I already have done some jquery ajax calls before and I am currently trying to realize a Wordpress pluging.

There I am trying to pass an array in Javascript using Ajax Jquery to a Php page using POST request. Ajax request is correctly achieved ( success and done events are triggered ) but when I am accessing the page $_POST is empty.
I even tried in the code below to simply put simple string data but I can't access it in php page.

This is my Jquery code :

```
$('#Enregistrer').click(function(){
    saveArray= new Array();
    var i=0;
    $('.q1').each(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass('tablesorter-filter-row')==true){
            // doing nothing
        }
        else{
            saveArray[i]=new Array();
            for (var j=0; j<6; j++){
                if ($(this).children().eq(j).hasClass('m1') || $(this).children().eq(j).hasClass('m2')){
                    var value = $(this).children().eq(j).children('select').val();
                }
                
                else{
                var value = $(this).children().eq(j).html();
                }
                saveArray[i][j]= value;
            }
        i++;
        }
    });
    console.log(saveArray);
    var data = 'test';
    $.ajax({
        url:'../api/send_form.php',
        method:'POST',
        data: { 'data': data },
       
        success: function(resp){
            console.log('ok');
            window.location='../api/send_form.php'; 
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }


    });
});
```

If you need more details don't hesitate, this is my first post on stackoverflow.I try to be as precise as possible.
Thanks

Comment: maybe becuz your ajax is missing `dataType: ?,` also another problem I found is you using quotes in your data should look like this: `data: { data: data },`

Comment: @ChrisG I already tried this but it didn't work at all. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

maybe your attempt is missing the type: 'POST', also added a few more elements

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'html', 
            type: 'POST',
            url:'../api/send_form.php',
            method:'POST',
            data: { data: data },
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function(resp){
                console.log('ok');
                window.location='../api/send_form.php'; 
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }


        });
```

Comment: Hi, I try this and It is not working again.
Thanks a lot for sharing ideas.

Comment: dang, sorry no idea whats the problem, the answer I gave u works for me, last thing I can think of is, change `dataType: 'html'` to `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: I already tried json format but the ajax method doesn't work poperly and not even redirect to my php page then .  when I try json I have the following error : SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Comment: ok but did you check if your send_form.php is receiving the data that you sent?

Comment: No, As i mentioned in my topic the problem is that $_POST is empty ( then undefinded) in my send.form.php